# IOS Kiosk Mode Coding

Tags: ios, ipad, jailbreak

I am looking to setup a one off application on my Developer iPad that prevents the usage of the home button (and preferably the lock button too). I would like to password protect leaving the application essentially. Best way to do that would be what?

Answer (score 3):

see my answer here [Lock-down iPhone/iPod/iPad so it can only run one app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011774/lock-down-iphone-ipod-ipad-so-it-can-only-run-one-app)

The lock button would still be active however so the device would be able to be rebooted. You would need a case that protected the lock button, that is the method Apple use in their stores.

Answer (score 2):

Without rooting your iPad I'm not aware that it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

### A way to do it manually:

- Make the following selection ***Settings->General->Accessiblity->Guided
     access*** and *enable* it and *set the password*
- Open the app to be locked
- *Triple click the home button* continuously that's it its the app gets
     locked
- To unlock triple click the home button continuously give the
     password While it asks that's it app is unlocked

**Note:**

This solution works from iOS 6 only.