# Is there a way to programmatically check if some specific mobileconfig has been activated?

Tags: ios, kiosk

This solution for an iOS kiosk mode (disabling the home button and on iPad the multitasking gesture) is really great, finally there is a possibility to implement a kiosk mode on iPads (even though it's quite complicated to activate and deactivate).

[Lock-down iPhone/iPod/iPad so it can only run one app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011774/lock-down-iphone-ipod-ipad-so-it-can-only-run-one-app/8994690#8994690)

I want to use this with a exam/quiz/e-assessement app. But how can my app check if this "kiosk" mode is actually active? Is there a way to programmatically check if some specific mobileconfig has been activated?

Comment: Maybe it would be possible to add some certificate to the mobileconfig file so that the exam server could only be reached with that certificate being active?

Comment: Ah, another idea: What if that quiz app would be distributed as an Enterprise app (not through the App Store). Maybe then it would be possible to combine the enterprise distribution provisioning profile with the kiosk mobileconfig, so only after that profile is active, the quiz app can run? Unfortunately I don't know much about enterprise app deployment and those profiles.

Answer (score 1):

Use an MDM tool, like AppBlade. Here's a video on our kiosk mode functionality http://vimeo.com/50632312

Comment: Per the FAQ, you should probably make it more clear that you're affiliated with AppBlade.