# Locking iPad to Safari and one webpage

Tags: ios, ipad

Can you somehow lock an iPad to Safari and only one webpage? I've found people locking iPad to certain apps but can't find this anywhere.

One app example:
[Lock-down iPhone/iPod/iPad so it can only run one app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011774/lock-down-iphone-ipod-ipad-so-it-can-only-run-one-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8994690/689356) to the question you link to:

> It is possible to put an iPad or iPhone into 'Store Demo' mode so that the home button and swipe to home gesture is disabled. If you have seen the iPads in the Apple Store running the smart sign apps then you will know what I mean.

So you could, for example, lock the device to Safari. But then it would be possible to navigate to any webpage.

What you need to do is to write a simple app that has a `UIWebView` that loads your site, and then put the device in 'Store Demo' mode afterwards. Also, depending on whether your site contains links to the outside world, you may have to implement `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` from the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol so that it refuses to leave your site.

Comment: How much simpler do you want it to be? It should take like 20 minutes to write this app.