# IPad-App needs to be crashsafe

Tags: xcode, ipad, crash

I'm developing an IPad-App that needs to be uncrashable, because the home screen with all the apps mustn't appear. The home button is covered by a case. Why I need this? Well, this app will be for promotion and feedback use in some public places.

If the home screen appears, everyone could do with the IPad what he want. It is already restricted by the IPhone-Configuration Tool as much as possible (sadly, internet connection is needed inside the App because there is an inside web browser that access preselected pages) but that isn't enough for me.

Is there a way to do one or more of following things to keep that app on foreground?

- The app implements inside error handling with a self-reset and self-reinit (something like this is possible in Windows). This is the resolution I like most. Is there such an API?
- The app crashes or the user quit/minimize it by a magnet, a sender or something like this, it restarts itself
- The app crashes but nothing inside the Home-Screen can be launched by everyone
- The app freezes after crash and give an alert, until it is relaunched by the staff member
- The app is watched by another app in background and gives alert to the staff by passing a call, sms, message etc to it, if it get closed or minimized.
- Another resolution similar to these

It needn't to be conpliant to the Appstore rules, because it won't be deployed by it. Just internal use. If there is only dirty code to do this, better than nothing.

The staff can push the home button, because it is able to open the case later.

The battery energy won't go out, because it is powered by a powersocket adapter all the time.

Comment: This may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011774/lock-down-iphone-ipod-ipad-so-it-can-only-run-one-app/8994690#8994690

Comment: Yes, you're looking for the store demo mode. By the way, if your app crashes, it will be restarted by the OS without turning back to the home screen.

Comment: @rokjarc I believe we are not supposed to gain rep by solutions provided by others. I just directed the OP to the right link :)

Comment: No, it just disable the home button and doesn't prevent the comeback to the homescreen after the app crashed. :-(