# iOS prevent app switching

Tags: ios, admin

I want to prevent app switching on an iPad.  I need to load a custom app for my employees who can use the app and do nothing else on the iPad.  I've heard that Apple allows custom apps to be loaded for commercial uses without going through the app store.

The basic settings under General > Restrictions let me turn off a few apps, but this is inadequate.  Ideally, I need two provide two modes: Guest and Admin.  The Admin would have ability to other apps and settings.  Would be great if the passcode functionality could be leveraged for this.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ability to disable the home button on the device is coming in iOS 6, as seen on [iOS 6 Preview: Accessibility](http://www.apple.com/ios/ios6/#accessibility).

You may be able to configure an iPad to disable the home button as well using Apple's Configuration Tool by setting `SBStoreDemoAppLock`. See another question on Stack Overflow, [Lock-down iPhone/iPod/iPad so it can only run one app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011774/lock-down-iphone-ipod-ipad-so-it-can-only-run-one-app).

Finally, as for deploying your apps, you probably want the [iOS Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/).