# iOS7 - Enter/Exit Single App Mode programmatically

Tags: ios, mdm

Consider a iOS7 device in a supervised mode (Via Apple configurator)
Is it possible to programmatically remove the device from the Single App mode (to change device settings) and then put it back in Single App Mode.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lock iOS app in single app mode programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20285136/lock-ios-app-in-single-app-mode-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

You can [use local .mobileconfig file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338035/installing-a-configuration-profile-on-iphone-programmatically) with proper configuration to reconfigure device programmatically