# how to enable/disable guided access programmatically objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm trying to create a small app which have only the functionality of **Guided Access** option.

> Settings> general > accessibility >Guided Access

In my application I want to set Guided access passcode and save to IPhone Settings.And user can enable/disable Guided access from my app.

How can I do this?

Comment: I doubt you can do this. Apps cannot change system settings.

Comment: it is possible here is link related to this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20285136/lock-ios-app-in-single-app-mode-programmatically

but i'm new in ios development so need working code or step by step guide

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27488537/how-can-i-programatically-enable-guided-access-kiosk-mode-on-an-iphone

Comment: yes i have check this to do so the device has to be supervised???and how to install MDM profile?