# Can I programmatically lock my iphone screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, jailbreak

I am working on a jailbroken iphone and I don't care if Apple rejects this app.
I am not talking about the simple keypad lock that can be achieved through

```
GSEventLockDevice();
```

I am talking about a passcode lock or some way to get the iphone stuck or to disable the home button?

Is it possible programmatically?

Comment: You can set a passcode (rather than keypad) lock in the Settings app. Just turn off "Simple Passcode."

Comment: @SumitMundra No this is not a duplicate of this question.See his answer.My requirement is entirely different.I stated in my question that "I am not talking about GSEventLockDevice".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called kiosk mode or guided mode.

Here are couple of articles generally describing this  subject:

http://joris.kluivers.nl/blog/2012/03/02/kiosk-mode-for-ios/
http://www.idownloadblog.com/2012/06/26/ios-6-guided-access/

Here is stackoverflow question with several approaches:

[Lock-down iPhone/iPod/iPad so it can only run one app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011774/lock-down-iphone-ipod-ipad-so-it-can-only-run-one-app/8994690#8994690)

And here is one more approach:

https://blog.compeople.eu/apps/?p=275