# iOS: possibility to keep an application always on top

Tags: ios

Is it possible to implement such a feature like this in iOS devices, allowing an app to be always on top?
Using private APIs/workarouds is not a problem.

Comment: if you're talking about a *kiosk-mode* app, [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5011774/119114)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 6, there is a feature called **Guided Access**

[image: Guided Access]

For details check:

1. [Apple Support](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5509)
2. [Guided Access](http://osxdaily.com/2012/09/25/enable-guided-access-ios/)
3. [Kiosk Mode](http://www.macgasm.net/2012/09/20/tip-how-to-turn-on-guided-access-in-ios-6-put-ipad-into-guest-user-mode/)