# Restrict iPad to only one application

Tags: ios, ipad, configuration, restrict

I am developing an iPad application & I want to keep use only my application in iPad. User is not able to make any changes with Home button too.

1. I have tried same thing with "Guided Access". But, it will stop push notification also.
2. I have tried it with iPhone configuration Utility. But, I am not able to find any 
   restriction for Home button.

So, anyone have any idea how can I implement it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011774/lock-down-iphone-ipod-ipad-so-it-can-only-run-one-app

Comment: I think Guided Access is the only way to limit the home button, so I don't think there is anyway around the notification issue.

Comment: @Prince Thanks for your reply. I have tried to create same profile using iPhone configuration utility. But, SBStoreDemoAppLock key is not found. So, can you please tell me, how I can make it into my configuration profile..

Comment: @ Michael Thanks for the comments. I have tried to make it with guided access. But, I am not able to get any incoming call also after keep it on. So, I guess, I will not get any iMessage also.

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable the Home button from the sandbox.You have to use the physical accessories to stop the Home button action, after opening your application.

Comment: @ Krishna Thanks for your comments. With the help of iPhone configuration utility or Guided Access, I am able to do it. But, I have some restriction in both ways. So, I am looking for better way from both.