# iOS app - on quit ask for password

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad-mini

I am building iOS app for promo. The client asked that people using it should never quit it, so I got an idea.

When people are trying to quit, they would be asked to enter the password, otherwise it's impossible. Is there a solution to this?

I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Quit? Is it for the AppStore, or for presentation/demo? If for demo, there is a way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011774/lock-down-iphone-ipod-ipad-so-it-can-only-run-one-app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the steps to easily disable the home button :

1. Launch the Settings app from the Home screen of your iPhone or iPad Tap on General.
2. Scroll down towards the bottom of the screen and tap on
   Accessibility.
3. Under the Learning section, tap on Guided Access.
4. If it's not already, turn the toggle next to Guided Access to the On
   position, then choose a passcode.
5. After having deployed your application on the device, open it and triple tap the home button.
6. Set your options and then tap on start.

You can leave the guided access mode by triple tapping the home button again, it will ask you for the passcode you set before.

[Here](http://www.pwlk.net/blog/iphoneipad-tutorial-disable-home-button-and-touch/) is a link for more details (and illustrated with photos)

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is not possible I guess. See for quitting any app the user can simply press the big quit button on the ipad or iphone and then the app would go into the background nevertheless.

You can't prevent the user from quitting. If you try to prevent it, the OS will terminate the app directly. With iOS 4.0, you can have tasks that are allowed to complete in the background.
 Check [this](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) out.

For an overview about running tasks.