# Problems with SBStoreDemoAppLock on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, security, kiosk

I'm trying to implement a kiosk mode on some iPads.

I came across this excellent post [Lock-down iPhone/iPod/iPad so it can only run one app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011774/lock-down-iphone-ipod-ipad-so-it-can-only-run-one-app) but have run into some problems running it on my iPad 2 with 7.0.4 installed on it.

I have tried using the linked sample http://ipadhire.co.nz/lockdown.mobileconfig as well as rolling my own, but constantly have issues. However, they appear to work just fine on the iOS Simulator which is running 7.0.3.

The Console output is as follows :

```
Jan 30 16:24:14 hipgnosiss-iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleKeyStore::device_state_transition: Device UnLocked, lockstate=0
Jan 30 16:24:23 hipgnosiss-iPad profiled[159] <Notice>: (Error) MC: Could not load MCProfileTrustA.bundle
Jan 30 16:24:23 hipgnosiss-iPad profiled[159] <Notice>: (Error) MC: Could not load MCProfileTrustB.bundle
Jan 30 16:24:23 hipgnosiss-iPad profiled[159] <Notice>: (Error) MC: MCDefaultsPayload Can't parse payload: NSError:
Desc   : The payload “Home Button Lock” is invalid.
Sugg   : Profile “Home Button Lock” has an invalid signature.
US Desc: The payload “Home Button Lock” is invalid.
US Sugg: Profile “Home Button Lock” has an invalid signature.
Domain : MCPayloadErrorDomain
Code   : 2000
Type   : MCFatalError
Params : (
    "Home Button Lock"
)
...Underlying error:
NSError:
Desc   : Profile “Home Button Lock” has an invalid signature.
US Desc: Profile “Home Button Lock” has an invalid signature.
Domain : MCDefaultsErrorDomain
Code   : 10001
Type   : MCFatalError
Params : (
    "Home Button Lock"
)
Extra info:
{
    isPrimary = 1;
}
Jan 30 16:24:23 hipgnosiss-iPad profiled[159] <Notice>: (Error) MC: Cannot create profile of type “com.apple.defaults.managed”. Error: NSError:
Desc   : The payload “Home Button Lock” is invalid.
Sugg   : Profile “Home Button Lock” has an invalid signature.
US Desc: The payload “Home Button Lock” is invalid.
US Sugg: Profile “Home Button Lock” has an invalid signature.
Domain : MCPayloadErrorDomain
Code   : 2000
Type   : MCFatalError
Params : (
    "Home Button Lock"
)
...Underlying error:
NSError:
Desc   : Profile “Home Button Lock” has an invalid signature.
US Desc: Profile “Home Button Lock” has an invalid signature.
Domain : MCDefaultsErrorDomain
Code   : 10001
Type   : MCFatalError
Params : (
    "Home Button Lock"
)
Extra info:
{
    isPrimary = 1;
}
Jan 30 16:24:23 hipgnosiss-iPad profiled[159] <Notice>: (Error) MC: Profile MCConfigurationProfile 0x15541c70, version 1:
Display Name: “Home Button Lock”
Description : “Disables Home Button”
Identifier  : com.hbkill
UUID        : 614D1FE3-F80D-4643-AF6B-D10C4CC8737A
Organization: NZ iPad Hire (ipadhire.co.nz)
Is Stub     : No
Locked      : No
Encrypted   : No
Trusted     : 0
Signed      : No
 Can't parse profile: NSError:
Desc   : The profile “Home Button Lock” is invalid.
Sugg   : Profile “Home Button Lock” has an invalid signature.
US Desc: The profile “Home Button Lock” is invalid.
US Sugg: Profile “Home Button Lock” has an invalid signature.
Domain : MCProfileErrorDomain
Code   : 1000
Type   : MCFatalError
Params : (
    "Home Button Lock"
)
...Underlying error:
NSError:
Desc   : The payload “Home Button Lock” is invalid.
Sugg   : Profile “Home Button Lock” has an invalid signature.
US Desc: The payload “Home Button Lock” is invalid.
US Sugg: Profile “Home Button Lock” has an invalid signature.
Domain : MCPayloadErrorDomain
Code   : 2000
Type   : MCFatalError
Params : (
    "Home Button Lock"
)
...Underlying error:
NSError:
Desc   : Profile “Home Button Lock” has an invalid signature.
US Desc: Profile “Home Button Lock” has an invalid signature.
Domain : MCDefaultsErrorDomain
Code   : 10001
Type   : MCFatalError
Params : (
    "Home Button Lock"
)
Extra info:
{
    isPrimary = 1;
}Extra info:
{
    isPrimary = 1;
}
Jan 30 16:24:23 hipgnosiss-iPad profiled[159] <Notice>: (Error) MC: Failed to parse profile data. Error: NSError:
Desc   : The profile “Home Button Lock” is invalid.
Sugg   : Profile “Home Button Lock” has an invalid signature.
US Desc: The profile “Home Button Lock” is invalid.
US Sugg: Profile “Home Button Lock” has an invalid signature.
Domain : MCProfileErrorDomain
Code   : 1000
Type   : MCFatalError
Params : (
    "Home Button Lock"
)
...Underlying error:
NSError:
Desc   : The payload “Home Button Lock” is invalid.
Sugg   : Profile “Home Button Lock” has an invalid signature.
US Desc: The payload “Home Button Lock” is invalid.
US Sugg: Profile “Home Button Lock” has an invalid signature.
Domain : MCPayloadErrorDomain
Code   : 2000
Type   : MCFatalError
Params : (
    "Home Button Lock"
)
...Underlying error:
NSError:
Desc   : Profile “Home Button Lock” has an invalid signature.
US Desc: Profile “Home Button Lock” has an invalid signature.
Domain : MCDefaultsErrorDomain
Code   : 10001
Type   : MCFatalError
Params : (
    "Home Button Lock"
)
Extra info:
{
    isPrimary = 1;
}Extra info:
{
    isPrimary = 1;
}
Jan 30 16:24:23 hipgnosiss-iPad profiled[159] <Notice>: (Error) MC: Profile cannot be queued for installation. Error: NSError:
Desc   : Invalid Profile
Sugg   : The payload “Home Button Lock” is invalid.
US Desc: Invalid Profile
US Sugg: The payload “Home Button Lock” is invalid.
Domain : MCInstallationErrorDomain
Code   : 4000
Type   : MCFatalError
...Underlying error:
NSError:
Desc   : The profile “Home Button Lock” is invalid.
Sugg   : Profile “Home Button Lock” has an invalid signature.
US Desc: The profile “Home Button Lock” is invalid.
US Sugg: Profile “Home Button Lock” has an invalid signature.
Domain : MCProfileErrorDomain
Code   : 1000
Type   : MCFatalError
Params : (
    "Home Button Lock"
)
...Underlying error:
NSError:
Desc   : The payload “Home Button Lock” is invalid.
Sugg   : Profile “Home Button Lock” has an invalid signature.
US Desc: The payload “Home Button Lock” is invalid.
US Sugg: Profile “Home Button Lock” has an invalid signature.
Domain : MCPayloadErrorDomain
Code   : 2000
Type   : MCFatalError
Params : (
    "Home Button Lock"
)
...Underlying error:
NSError:
Desc   : Profile “Home Button Lock” has an invalid signature.
US Desc: Profile “Home Button Lock” has an invalid signature.
Domain : MCDefaultsErrorDomain
Code   : 10001
Type   : MCFatalError
Params : (
    "Home Button Lock"
)
Extra info:
{
    isPrimary = 1;
}Extra info:
{
    isPrimary = 1;
}
```

Anyone have any suggestions of what I should look at to fix the problem? I do realize there are other ways to do kiosks, but this mode fits my needs the best.

--Bill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this doesn't seem possible on any physical device iOS 7+ in my testing.  Apple looks to have specifically quashed this to force people to use the app lock setting which requires the devices to be supervised by a Configurator.

I've had some success using MDM solutions (AirWatch or Meraki) to force single app mode without actually requiring the devices to be physically plugged into the supervising Mac daily.  You still have to setup supervision one time to allow the single app requirement to be pushed down from MDM though.