# Can I Lockdown iPad Browser to a Specific Web Application?

Tags: android, ipad, point-of-sale

I'm developing a Point-of-Sale solution to be deployed on an iPad. The application will be engineered as a web application. I've seen some great info on how to lock down the iPad to a specific application and so this gets me halfway to my solution; the application I lock down to will be the browser.

[Lock-down iPhone/iPod/iPad so it can only run one app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011774/lock-down-iphone-ipod-ipad-so-it-can-only-run-one-app)

Now, can I take this one step further? Can I lock down the browser to disallow ad-hoc browsing? I'd like to do this because I want to ensure that the user is constrained to the confines of the POS application at all times.

(If I can't do this, I'll need to write a small shim application to host my web application and I don't want to do this, because this violates the zero-install architecture we're trying to achieve.)

Alternatively, is there a way to achieve this with an Android tablet? As the application is constructed with HTML5, we are relatively agnostic as to the client device.

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

You could add the Website to the Homescreen. Then it appears as an app - maybe you can then lock it down with the mechanism you mentioned.